# Techniques to account for differences in misclassification "cost" on variables other than the outcome

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, caret, subsampling

Suppose you're in a classic classification context: you want to predict whether a patient has a certain virus. You are working in multiple regions (let's say 2 for simplicity: Region A and Region B) and realize that, while the infection rate is similar, the death rate for those who contract the virus is drastically different. Naturally you decide that you want to account for differences in misclassification cost relative to the region as well as the outcome/response. That is to say, you know the cost of a false negative in region A (higher death rate) is much higher than the cost of a false negative in region B (lower death rate) where "negative" means "no virus".

There is imbalance in your data in both the region and the outcome. The counts of the data look something like this:

[image]

The infection rate is 5% in both regions but the death rate is 7x higher in A.

Looking for ideas on any modeling techniques (like a type of subsampling) or metrics (a la f_beta score) out there that can specifically handle this. Also, I'm a heavy R user (love caret) so any tools in R would be helpful.

Note: I'm looking for ideas that scale for N regions and where the number of records in some regions may be too small to build separate models for each.

Thanks!

Comment: If you look for posts by Frank Harrell, you’ll find some thoughts on how to assess performance when you do classification.

Comment: For now, I've decided to use case weights with regularized logistic regression. Ironically, Frank seems to suggest in several places that it is generally unnecessary, but I am seeing marked improvement in my objective/cost optimization when doing so.